# Get statistics from subgroups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I have this dataframe with data where df['two']=0 is filtered and then I grouped it in consecutive "subgroups" showing the answer in "results".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import operator

index = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p']
df  = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
df['one']  = range(16)
df['two'] = [-1,0,0,-1,1,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1]
df['three'] =  [0,1,3,5,5,8,10,12,13,17,18,20,22,24,25,26]

df_filter = df[((df['two']==0))]
df_filter_list = df_filter.one.tolist()

results = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(df_filter_list), lambda (i,x):i-x):
        group = map(operator.itemgetter(1), g)
        results.append(group)

print results 
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Now my question is, how can I use the values of "results" and go back to get statistics for each different subgroup of a certain column?

For example if I want to know the average of df['three'] for the second "sub group" ([5,6] in the results) it would  be the average of the 5th and 6th rows for column 'three', so average of 5 and 8.
Or if I want to know the max of the third "subgroup" [9,10,11,12,13] it would be 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually just tweaking your answer a little bit and realizing how you used iloc, pointed me on exactly what I needed. Posting it in case useful for someone:

Instead of doing this that would give you the statistic of just subgroup 1:

```
results2=[]
for item in results[1]:
    results2.append(item -1)
sub = df.iloc[results2]
sub['three'].mean()
```

I just did this, that would give you the mean (or anything you need) of every subgroup.

```
for z in range(len(results)):
    sub =  df.iloc[results[z]]
    print sub['three'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must keep the original values in "results" you can use another list to "shift" the index (the value 1 in results[1] is for your first example of [5,6]):

```
results2=[]
for item in results[1]:
    results2.append(item -1)
```

Then get your sub-set:

```
sub = df.iloc[results2]
```

And compute the average:

```
sub['three'].mean()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Wasn't clear enough before. What if i need to get the mean for each one of the subgroups in a very big database and not just  one of them? was trying to do a "for i in range(len(results))" before the "for item in results[i]" that you did but not working for me...